# Android- How to handle incomplete image uploads

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-post

In the app Im working on at the moment we are allowing the user to upload images to our server. Im doing this in an asyncTask thread and using httpMime and sending the image as a byte array in one of the multipart entity fields. Id say about 80 % of the time this works great. The images show up on the server in a mySql table as longBlob's no problem. The other 20 percent the image gets lost on upload due to various changes in network conditions or on older less capable devices that Ive tested on (HTC dream/tmobile G1) the memory would poop out. The memory issues Ive dealt with by adding a series of catch blocks so that is no longer an issue.  Ive tried playing with httpconnectionparams but Im not to sure if that had much effect on the problem.

How ever.....now I need a little guidance as to how to handle images lost due to network issues such as latency, switches from 4g to edge, and other problems such as total loss of coverage. I was thinking about a background service which would check any returning ojects from the server and if the object had no image associated with it, queue the background service to retry an upload.  My main concern isnt that a image isnt making it to my server during testing but occasionally when testing while driving or somewhere on the edge of tower service the app will transmit only a partial image which I can see in my database.

So.....my question to the community this time is how have you handled such a problem. One way I was thinking of trying is sending the actual size of the file along in the multipart transmission to the server and if when the image hits the php I have set up and doesnt match the size of the int representing the file size then send back a flag value in the response. Then based on the response the app gets back it could possibly fire off the asynctask again to reupload the photo. That approach would be pretty simple to set up but I would like something a bit more fail proof and besides if the user goes into no coverage for along time I would have this zombie process chewing up their battery.....no good.

Like always any help on the matter with opinions, links, or other help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok no prob.....since I didnt get any good responses pointing me in any direction I implemented my own backup service to check the data in the server against that which resides on the phone. If it matches no prob if its short than ask if user wants to re-upload. Works great....thanks to me hurray lol!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. I really doubt you handled out of memory problems just with try/catch blocks (unless by "handle" you meant: "it doesn't crash because we don't let these users upload big images anymore").
2. Which library are you using for HTTP connections? I ask this because I recently ran into an OOM issue when uploading as well.
3. I'm also a bit confused regarding your failed uploads, your server should be returning an appropriate response and your client should be expecting this. Anything other than (say) a 200 should result in the Android UI letting the user know that the image upload failed and that he should try again. Your AsyncTask (hopefully you're using one) should catch these exceptions and handle them appropriately. Unless there's something else wrong with your server, you should not be returning 200s on "half uploads", dropped connections and cases like that.

Comment: Lol yes I magically handled my out of memory with just one single try/catch block.....dude.....cmon and have some faith that I might just know what im doing lol.....what I did was catch OutOfMemoryExceptions trickling down until I didnt get any testing on lesser devices. so my try catch goes something like this.....try{my.process();}catch(OOME ){my.process2()} and so on.....the library Im using is the httpmime-4.1.1 and it works pretty good. The server does send back a response which I catch in the log at the moment. But heres the problem....the setup I have now does not check for half uploads

Comment: So if you can give me a pointer or two on how I should handle half uploads or failed responses I would appreciate it very much :)

Comment: Hmmm...I used HTTPMime too and didn't run into memory issues. I actually used it to solve the issues that I had with another library. And I still don't get why you needed an extra service to know if your upload was successful, but if it works for you, that's great.

Comment: I had to create something so I could be absolutely positive the images not only made it to the server but made it in one solid piece which was my problem. The memory issues where due to the sheer volume of images coming to and leaving from the phone but not the use of the httpmime library. But yeah my service is great.....everyone tells me so too ;)